# Como manter um app rodando em segundo plano mesmo com a aplicação fechada?

Tags: ionic, mobile

Estou criando um app de envio de coordenadas e preciso que o mesmo continue fazendo o envio mesmo com ele fechado.
Usei alguns plugins como background mode porém após o fechamento do app ele não funcionava.

Após a atualizaçao do android 12, tive muitos problemas com crash por conta desse plugin.

Como posso manter esse envio de coordenadas mesmo com a aplicação fechada?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -2):

utilize o Plugin [cordova-plugin-background-geolocation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v5/native/background-geolocation), este plugin é exclusivo para envio de geolocalização e é otimizado para minimizar a utilização da bateria.